# Existence of skew lines in 3D

Tags: geometry, axiomatic-geometry

I need to prove existence of skew lines in three dimensional space?
I'm looking for starting point.
Is it possible to prove only using axioms of geometry?

Comment: If you can construct a cube. Then you can find skew lines.

Comment: it should be possible to prove using ONLY axioms of geometry, but then the question is which exactly axioms you want to use, and at any rate it might be rather tedious. On the other hand constructing a specific example is rather obvious, e.g. use a cube (as suggested in the previous comment), or a tetrahedron. Alternatively, use a 3D coordinate system with $x$-, $y$- and $z$-axes, and take the $x$-axis together with a line parallel to the $y$-axis going through the point $(0,0,1)$ (with $z=1$. If you use axioms only, do you have your favorite list of axioms for three dimensional space?

Comment: Won't this do? The lines $\{(x,y,z)\mid y=0=z\}$ and $\{(x,y,z)\mid x=0\text{ and }y=1\}$ are skew, so skew lines surely exist.

Comment: Do you assume that you have the equations that define the lines? How you define two parallel lines? Define a plane that include the first line, parallel to the other line.